# while para o loop com scanf

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer um relatório em c, e quando digito o primeiro caractere o programa acaba.

````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{

    int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, x, e;
        
        do
        {
            printf( "Escolha entre \n\n a, b, c, d, e(fechar) \n\n");
            scanf(" %d", &x);
        
            if(scanf(" %d", &x) == a) 
            { 
                a++;
            }
            
            if(scanf(" %d", &x) == b)
            {
                b++;
            }
            
            if(scanf(" %d", &x) == c)
            { 
                c++; 
            }
            
            if(scanf(" %d", &x) == d)
            { 
                d++; 
            }
        }
        while (scanf(" %d", &x) != e);
        
        printf("\nTotal vezes de a: %d", a);
        printf("\nTotal vezes de b: %d", b);
        printf("\nTotal vezes de c: %d", c);
        printf("\nTotal vezes de d: %d", d);
}```
````

Comment: Uma grave confusão entre o que é uma variável e o que é uma constante. Sua mensagem diz `Escolha entre \n\n a, b, c, d, e(fechar)` mas em seus testes você compara o que foi lido com uma variável inteira, todas elas inicializadas com 0.

Comment: fora o fato de que você tá usando scanf atoa a cada loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Declarando variável de forma errada.

Inicialmente você está cometendo o erro de tentar ler caracteres com uma variável de valor inteiro.

> int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, ***x***, e;

Quando na verdade você deveria estar declarando.

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
char x;
```

Já que o pretendido nessa questão é justamente contabilizar quantas vezes as 4 letras foram  fornecidas pelo usuário, em um loop que só será finalizado quando existir a leitura da letra "**e**", ou seja, a variável `e` que você declarou, nessa situação não é necessária.
Além disso, posteriormente é necessário também alterar o valor de entrada de:

> scanf(" %d", &x);

Para:

```
scanf (" %c ", &x);
```

Já que anteriormente, como alteramos o tipo da variável, de *int* para *char* devemos também alterar o tipo de leitura de variável do scanf.

- Comando `if` está declarado de forma incorreta.

Você está utilizando de forma errado o comando `if`, recomendo revisar um pouco sobre. Onde você declarou da seguinte maneira:

> if(scanf(" %d", &x) == a)

Quando na verdade a forma mais correta nessa situação seria declarar:

```
if (x == 'a') /* Verificando se é verdade que a variável "x" possui como valor a letra a */
```

Lembrando que nesse tipo de comparação, só será verdade caso o usuário digite uma letra minúscula.

- Comando `do while` está declarado de forma incorreta.

Da mesma forma que o comando `if`, você declarou errado o comando `do while`. Onde você declarou da seguinte maneira:

> while (scanf(" %d", &x) != e);

Quando na verdade a forma correta de declarar este `while` nessa situação, seria assim:

```
while (x != 'e'); /* O loop só cessará quando a letra "e" for declarada pelo usuário. */
```

- Código corrigido sem muitas alterações.

Com essas alterações citadas acima, o seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
int main(){

int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
char x; 

printf( "Escolha entre as seguintes letras: \n\n a, b, c, d, e(Para Fechar) \n\n");         

    do
    {
        scanf("%c", &x);
    
        if(x == 'a') 
        { 
            a++;
        }
        
        if(x == 'b') 
        {
            b++;
        }
        
        if(x == 'c') 
        { 
            c++; 
        }
        
        if(x == 'd') 
        { 
            d++; 
        }
    }
    while (x != 'e');
    
    printf("\nTotal de vezes de a: %d", a);
    printf("\nTotal de vezes de b: %d", b);
    printf("\nTotal de vezes de c: %d", c);
    printf("\nTotal de vezes de d: %d", d);
    
return 0;
```

Lembrando que mantive o código original feito por você, mesmo existindo formas mais corretas de se fazer tal algoritmo desejado.